# How to understand expr.const.cast clause 8 in C++ standard N3337?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, const-cast

In [C++ draft standard N3337](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/) section [[expr.const.cast]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.post#expr.const.cast-8):

> The following rules define the process known as casting away constness. In these rules T<sub>n</sub> and X<sub>n</sub> represent types. For two pointer types:
>
> X1 is T1 *cv*<sub>1,1</sub> * ⋯ *cv*<sub>1,*N*</sub> *  where T1 is not a pointer type
>
> X2 is T2 *cv*<sub>2,1</sub> * ⋯ *cv*<sub>2,*M*</sub> * where T2 is not a pointer type
>
> *K* is min (*N*,*M*)
>
> casting from X1 to X2 casts away constness if, for a non-pointer type T there does not exist an implicit conversion (Clause [conv](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/conv)) from:
>
> T *cv*<sub>1,(*N-K*+1)</sub> * *cv*<sub>1,(*N-K*+2)</sub> *⋯ *cv*<sub>1,*N*</sub> *
>
> to
>
> T *cv*<sub>2,(*M-K*+1)</sub> * *cv*<sub>2,(*M-K*+2)</sub> *⋯ *cv*<sub>2,*M*</sub> *

I can't understand the clause, so I looked up the corresponding clause in [C++ draft standard N4659](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/),  [[expr.const.cast]/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.const.cast#7):

> A conversion from a type T1 to a type T2 casts away constness if T1 and T2 are different, there is a cv-decomposition of T1 yielding n such that T2 has a [cv-decomposition](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/conv.qual#def:cv-decomposition) of the form
>
> *cv*<sub>0</sub><sup>2</sup>*P*<sub>0</sub><sup>2</sup> *cv*<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup>*P*<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup> ⋯ *cv*<sub>n-1</sub><sup>2</sup>*P*<sub>n-1</sub><sup>2</sup> *cv*<sub>n</sub><sup>2</sup> U<sub>2</sub>
>
> and there is no qualification conversion that converts T1 to
>
> *cv*<sub>0</sub><sup>2</sup>*P*<sub>0</sub><sup>1</sup> *cv*<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup>*P*<sub>1</sub><sup>1</sup> ⋯ *cv*<sub>n-1</sub><sup>2</sup>*P*<sub>n-1</sub><sup>1</sup> *cv*<sub>n</sub><sup>2</sup> U<sub>1</sub>.

But I still can't understand the relationship between `T1,T2` and `T`. Help me, who can interpret the clause?

Answer (score 1):

In the older version, a (mostly) arbitrary *T* is introduced just to dispense with the issue that

```
const int *p=0;
auto q=reinterpret_cast<char*>(p);  // error: casts away constness
```

is changing from `int` to `char`.  It gets effectively rewritten as

```
auto __q=reinterpret_cast<const char*>(p);  // ok
char *q=__q;  // error
```

The newer version simply explicitly reuses *U1* rather than inventing *T*.